# Exercise: Show an operator in Hlbert space is compact

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

> Let $\;l^2\;=\{ (x_1,x_2,\dots) : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\vert x_n
>  \vert}^2 \lt +\infty\}\;$ be our Hilbert space and consider the
>   operators $\;T_i: l^2 \rightarrow l^2 \;$ as
>
> $T_1x=(a_1x_1,0,\dots)\;\\T_2x=(a_1x_1,a_2x_2,0,\dots)\\ .\;\\.\;
>  \\T_nx=(a_1x_1,a_2x_2,\dots,a_nx_n,0,\dots)\;$
>
> where $\;a_i \in \mathbb C\;$ $\forall 1\le i \le n\;$
>
> Prove that each $\;T_i\;$ is compact.

**My thought:**

I know a finite range operator is compact. And it seems this is the statement I need in order to solve this exercise. However it's a bit unclear to me why $\;dimRan(T_i)\lt +\infty\;\;\forall i$ since $\;T_ix\;$ includes infinite number of zeros. Also each $\;T_i\;$ reminds me -in a kind of way- of the linear span of $\;x\;$ but it isn't the linear span...

I 'm having a really hard time getting my head around this so any help would be valuable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do the $\cdots$ mean above? Did you mean $0,\cdots$ instead?

Comment: @copper.hat yeah, I just fixed that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $T_n(x) \in \operatorname{sp} \{ e_1,...,e_n\}$, hence 
$T_n$ has finite dimensional range.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your answer! I want to be sure that I have fully understood this so I 'd like to ask you: If I take $\;x\in l^2\;$ such that $\;T_nx=(a_1x_1,a_2x_2,\dots,a_nx_n,0,\dots)\;$ then I can write $\;T_nx=a_1x_1e_1+a_2x_2e_2+\dots+a_nx_ne_n\;$. In order $\;T_n(x) \in \operatorname{sp} \{ e_1,...,e_n\}\;$  shouldn't each $\;a_ix_i \in \mathbb C\;$? Why does this hold?

Comment: It was a silly question I made! In my defense, I had just woken up! You're right. I realised it later after I asked you but I was too lazy to delete the comment....:)

Comment: No problem! ${}{}$

Answer (score 2):

All the operators you list are finite-rank, so compact.

More generally, if you define 
$$
Tx=(a_1x_1,a_2x_2,\ldots)
$$
then $T$ is compact if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Comment: I can see why $\;\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=0$ if  $\;T\;$ is compact but not vice versa. $\; {\vert \vert T_nx-Tx \vert \vert}^2 = \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} { \vert a_i \vert }^2 {\vert x_i \vert}^2\;$  How do I procced and why I conclude that $\; \vert \vert T_n-T \vert \vert \to 0\;$ .. ? However thanks a lot!

Comment: With $k_n=\max\{|a_{n+1}|,|a_{n+2}|,\ldots\}$, $$\|T_nx-Tx\|^2\leq k_n^2\,\|x\|^2. $$

Comment: So letting $\;n \to \infty\;$ $\;{ k_n}^2 \to 0\;$. It was in front of my eyes... you've been very helpful!

Comment: My pleasure :) $ $